# Flexible Message

Tags: unity, architecture

I'm looking to create a way to show messages to the player. The message should be able to have pictures, different options and outcomes.

What's the best way to design this?

Comment: How familiar are you with [the Unity UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIToolkits.html)? And what's your priority between having a high grade of flexibility and making it quick and easy to write new messages?

Comment: I have some knowledge. Preferably it would be quick and easy to create new messages.
My initial plan is to use scriptableobjects for messages, and for the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Anatomy of the message popup

[image: Message Popup]
My approach would be to create a UI canvas with a single panel "message box" which can be toggled on and off by a script.

In order for the message box to always arrange all its content vertically it has a [VerticalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html) with "Child-Alignment: Middle Center". I switched off "Force Child Expand" in the vertical layout group because I want the children to control their own size. That way the panel can adjust to the size of the children instead of the other way around.

In order for the panel to adjust its size to the amount of content it holds, I gave it a [ContentSizeFitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ContentSizeFitter.html). Both horizontal and vertical fit are set to "Preferred Size". (You will see a warning "Parent has a type of layout group component" in these content size fitters. This is not a problem in this case, because we are not using "Control Child Size" in the parent).

Both the headline text and the body text of the message also have a ContentSizeFitter with "Horizontal Fit: Unconstrained" and "Vertical Fit: Preferred Size". This makes the text box shrink and grow vertically depending on the amount of text in it. You might also notice that I am using Text Mesh Pro for all text elements. This is just a personal preference. I find TMP to be superior to the default text in several regards. But it works just as well with regular text.

## Adding logic

The buttons don't do anything yet. So I will add a script to the basic panel which has a method to handle button clicks. It takes the number of the button that was clicked as a parameter.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MessageBoxHelloWorld : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public void OptionClick(int optionNumber) {
        switch(optionNumber) {
            case 0:
                Debug.Log("You saved the world");
                break;
            case 1:
                Debug.Log("You conquered the world");
                break;
            case 2:
                Debug.Log("You destroyed the world");
                break;
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

As you can see, these just post a message to the console and then makes the message box disappear by destroying it. Adding more game-specific logic to these three options would be up to you.

Then I link each of the three buttons to the method in this script. Remember to add the number of the button to the text input below the method, so it knows which button the player pressed:

[image: Button]

## Making it reusable

Ok, now we created *one* message box, but you wanted to have several different messages.

### Prefabs

One option would be to just make this message box a prefab. You can then create a [prefab variant](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrefabVariants.html) of it for every message in your game. This gives you a workflow which is actually pretty similar to scriptable objects: Every message is an asset. But you now have a lot of flexibility regarding the design of each message, because you can add any UI elements you want to a message and change any of their settings. And you even get WYSIWYG editing for messages.

When it comes to implementing the logic for handling the player choices, then you will have to write a separate script for every message. In order to avoid code duplication, you might want to use object-oriented inheritance. Create a base-class which derives for MonoBehaviour and then have the classes which implement the events inherit from that class. That allows you to move common logic to the base class. When you notice that you have a lot of options in a lot of different messages which do exactly the same thing (like closing the message without doing anything), then you could move the onclick-handler method for those buttons to the base class. That way you don't need to program it individually for each message.

### The universal message box

But what if we want to make the message box entirely code-driven? There can be a lot of reasons for that. Perhaps you want some messages which are created entirely from code at runtime. Or perhaps you want to move the messages to an external file. Whatever your reason might be to not use prefabs, this should work for you.

Now we no longer have an unique script for each message, we have a script which can be used to display any message. It needs public method which allows us to set:

- The headline
- The image
- The text
- Any number of buttons and what happens when the player clicks on them.

The programming for this gets a bit more convoluted, but shouldn't be too difficult to implement on your own. The only thing which could get a bit more tricky is implementing the logic for the buttons. One thing you should know about here is how to set the event of a button at runtime. You can do that with the method  `button.onClick.AddListener`. That method requires a `UnityAction`. What is a UnityAction? It's a [delegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). Or in other words, an object which wraps a call to a method. So you can write code like that:

```
private void CloseMessageBox() {
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

/* ... */

    button.onClick.AddListener(this.CloseMessageBox);
```

Or you can create an anonymous method in-place in form of a [lambda expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions):

```
button.onClick.AddListener( 
    () => {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Something like "the universal message box" is what I am looking for. How would I store the logic of my buttons when creating messages? Should I store them in separate scripts that inherits from a class like MessageOption?

Comment: @Kluckmuck That depends on a lot of factors. There is no ideal solution, just the solution which is ideal for *your* game. Some games might get away with a completely data-driven approach where button actions are nothing but data. Others require a tiny bit of code but only occasionally, in which case it might be a good idea to work with lambda expressions. You could write one large helper-class with all the action handlers, probably parametrized. You could write a script for each message. Or if you have very complex handlers, you could write a separate class for each button.